# Python Panda Percentages Calculations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Trying to Calculate Percentages on Python Pandas

```
   1  2
0  A  0
1  A  1
2  A  2
3  B  0
4  B  0
5  B  1.5
6  B  0
```

Output of Percentage of A's and B's with a score higher than 0.

```
A = 66%
B = 25%
```

Answer (score 3):

- Create a boolean filter on the second column (`(df['2'] > 0)`)
- Group it by the first column
- Aggregate with `sum`  and `size` (sum will count the ones that satisfy the condition)
- Divide sum by size to get the percentage:

---

```
res = (df['2'] > 0).groupby(df['1']).agg(['sum', 'size'])    
res['sum'] / res['size']

Out: 
1
A    0.666667
B    0.250000
dtype: float64
```

This can be done in a more compact way with a lambda expression:

```
df.groupby('1')['2'].agg(lambda x: (x > 0).sum() / x.size)
Out: 
1
A    0.666667
B    0.250000
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

but I suspect that the first one is more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [3]: df['2'].gt(0).groupby(df['1']).mean()
Out[3]:
1
A    0.666667
B    0.250000
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @ayhan, i feel bit bad as i i've stolen your `(df['2'] > 0).groupby(df['1'])` part :)

Comment: This is better, no worries :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't mind me...
I'm [**on a kick**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_a_kick) where I'm solving everything with [**`np.bincount`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) and [**`pd.factorize`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html)

```
f, u = df['1'].factorize()
pd.Series(
    np.bincount(f, df['2'].values > 0) / np.bincount(f),
    u
)

A    0.666667
B    0.250000
dtype: float64
```

---

One-liner version for fun!

```
(lambda w, g, f, u: pd.Series(g(f, w) / g(f)))(
    df['2'].values > 0, np.bincount, *pd.factorize(df['1'].values)
)
```

---

**Naive Timing**

```
%timeit df['2'].gt(0).groupby(df['1']).mean()
%timeit df.groupby('1')['2'].agg(lambda x: (x > 0).sum() / x.size)
%timeit (lambda w, g, f, u: pd.Series(g(f, w) / g(f)))(df['2'].values > 0, np.bincount, *pd.factorize(df['1'].values))

1000 loops, best of 3: 697 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 117 µs per loop
```